# Copy-Pasting Text into Bodies

Tags: bug, ios-app, paste

While I can post external texts into question and answer bodies, it preserves the old font style, spacing and size (although the markdown display won’t be affected by that.)

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 11.0.3 (Build 15A432)

Comment: I'm afraid there's nobody to fix this bug, the single iOS developer has been re-assigned. I think they still fix critical bugs (i.e. bugs stopping people from using the app) but this one isn't critical, so likely won't be fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wonder why I haven’t found that. I searched before asking because it occurred to me that *someone* must have noticed. Can you dupe-hammer it? I can’t selfclose in the app. // Why won’t they make the app open source? I can imagine with such a strong community, it wouldn’t take long until a working version is built and bugs are fixed.

Comment: I searched for `[ios-app] paste is:q` and it was one of the 15 results. Probably app search isn't really good, I never use the app to search. As for hammer, [tag:bug] tag is the only one (of the "base" tags) where I don't have hammer. No worry, there is review and it will get closed soon. :)

Comment: Ah, the is:q. Thanks for that, on my fifteen in the app answers are included. I searched for newest (and just did that again right now, this Q didn’t even show up there)....

Comment: Sure, always a pleasure to share knowledge. :)

Comment: I've removed the part about comments, since that was already reported many times before.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks, I reopened the question.